# How to control relative path in php

Tags: php, html, path

In my project, I have a problem for  href.

my html page is a.php, and its code is :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ulpin.com /css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
  dd{word-wrap:break-word;};
  </style>
  <title>SystemTitle</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/jquery-1.7.2-min.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <base target="_self"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
 <div class="container">
<center>
    <a href="active.php" class="btn">ManTest</a><br/><br/>
</center>
</div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

But it works fail. So I checked the page source code with firefox, When I click the href of static/js/jquery-1.7.2-min.js, it shows:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /o1ws1v/web/admin/static/js/jquery-1.7.2-min.js was not found on this server.
```

The src   is changed. "/o1ws1v/web/admin/" is added auto.

Why?

My fold struct is :

```
 /yjdata/www/www/o1ws1v/web/admin/a.php
 /yjdata/www/www/o1ws1v/web/static/js/jquery-1.7.2-min.js
 /yjdata/www/www/o1ws1v/web/static/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Otherwise, a.php is put in /yjdata/www/www/o1ws1v/web/, it works OK

Who can help me?

Comment: What you are using localhost?

Comment: What you are typing at address bar?

Comment: Please provide more details. Where is `a.php`? What is the folder structure?

Comment: Using `static/goods/` means that the folder `static/` is located in the same directory as your `a.php`! Would you provide your folders structure ?

Comment: Is the `static` folder is located under `/admin/` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui,static is located under web, see my update

Comment: @CBroe,my  root folder is /yjdata/www/www, but it seems it had been changed to /o1ws1v/web/admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple problem of paths.

When you are under `/yjdata/www/www/o1ws1v/web/admin/a.php` and use `src="static/js/jquery-1.7.2-min.js"`, this is waht happens :

```
--/yjdata/www/www/o1ws1v/web/admin/
                         |     |--- a.php    <-- You are here
                         |     |--- static/  <-- This is where the browser think that the static folder exists 
                         |--- static/        <-- This is where the folder really is !
```

So, what you need to do in the `a.php` is to go up a level in the src path :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/jquery-1.7.2-min.js">  </script>
```

The `..` to indicate the parent directory.

Comment: wow, that is great. it will add current dir to url while using relative way. thank you very much ,it works ok